# Set div to width and height of child image?

Tags: css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tbrtoaj/1/)

I have a div with class of container. The height of this div must equal the width. I have achieved this with:

```
.container{
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    position: relative;
}

.container:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

Inside the container is an image holder, and inside this an image. The image must be constrained, it's height or width must not exceed the container and still maintain aspect ratio. This is achieved by:

```
img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    max-height: 100%;  
    max-width: 100%; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;

}
```

My question concerns the image holder, I need this to be the same width and height as the image that is inside of it. How can I do this? Using CSS only please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1tbrtoaj/2/ ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien the height of the container div no longer equals the width

Comment: @panthro did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/1tbrtoaj/4/

Remove position: absolute from your img tag.

```
.container{
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    position: relative;
}

.container:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

.img-holder {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0000ff;
}

img{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    max-height: 100%;  
    max-width: 100%; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Image is now half way down container and container's height is now not the same as it's width

Comment: Positioning in the container can be fixed by removing padding-top: 100% from .container:before

Comment: Yes but - the container's height is now not the same as it's width

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1tbrtoaj/5/  How about this?  You can create another div to wrap around the container and give it fixed width and height, along with display: inline-block

Comment: This is a difficult question... I may come back to it at some point :)